# Is there a way to fit an image into an irregular shape using css

Tags: html, css

On the home page of my website, I want to my image to fill 100% of the screen width and only 95% of the height. Along the bottom edge of the image I also want to fill in a small circle with the image. I've attached an image of what I hope my end result will look like, as well as my current code.

So far I've figured out how to scale the image to 100% width and 95% height, but I'm stuck here.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please attach mentioned image. show us some of your code.

Comment: I see not image attached nor any debugging details of your attempt. A good start would be to read into `clip-path`